# How to set meta-data for my plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I found this snippet of code to retrieve data for a single plugin, within the wp-admin:

```
$plugin_data = get_plugin_data( __FILE__, $markup = true, $translate = true );
foreach($plugin_data as $k=>$v){
    echo $k . " = " . $v . "<br>";
}
```

It works to the extent that an associative array is output, but only one of the keys, 'TextDomain' actually has a value. I assume I'm supposed to set the values somewhere, and I thought that would be in the plugin commented header.

Here's the output from the foreach loop:

```
Name = 
PluginURI = 
Version = 
Description = 
Author = 
AuthorURI = 
TextDomain = custom-calculator
DomainPath = 
Network = 
Title = 
AuthorName =
```

Here's my header in the main plugin file:

```
/*
Plugin Name:    Custom Calculator
Plugin URI:     http://customcalc.com
Description:    A cost calculator.
Version:        1.2
Author:         John Doe
Author URI:     
License:        Commercial Single License
License URI:    
Text Domain:    cost-calculator
Domain Path:    /languages
*/
```

How do I set/access the values for the other fields, everything from PluginURI to Version, Description, Author, AuthorURI, Title, etc? Or, why aren't the values set in my plugin's header being properly output using `get_plugin_data()`?

---

I changed the code to the following, and now I get all values.

```
$plugin_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '\customcalc.php';
$plugin_data = get_plugin_data( $plugin_path );
echo "<br><br><br>";
foreach($plugin_data as $k=>$v){
    echo $k . " = " . $v . "<br>";
}
```

It's the difference between this:

```
__FILE__
```

... and this:

```
dirname(__FILE__) . '\customcalc.php';
```

Does it have something to do with my WordPress being on Windows and xampp, rather than a Linux OS? I don't know.

Comment: i try your code that use `get_plugin_data` and I obtain all datas. in which hook do you use this code ?

Comment: I got it working, going to add what I did as an answer.